# Element Creation in angular Material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to create an application in material angularJS. All the help on internet provides the html code for UI creation. I want to know if there is any method to create material angular ui elements in javascript file.
Help is appreciated
Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can create HTML elements in AngularJS in your script. This can be achieved by creating your own [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) or simply appending or prepending to the DOM. There is also ngBind that you can look into via this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

The following two simple examples show you append and prepend, yet I would recommend to look into each option available to assess what is the most suitable for your use case.

**Append**

```
var elementName = angular.element(document.querySelector('#divIDHere'));
elementName.append('<md-button class="md-raised">Button</md-button>');
```

**Prepend**

```
var elementName = angular.element(document.querySelector('#divIDHere'));
elementName.prepend('<md-button class="md-raised">Button</md-button>');
```

Comment: Is there any way apart from above mentioned code,as we have in openui5 
var button= new sap.m.Button();

Comment: You can of course create a directive as previously discussed, which will allow you full customisation of on page elements as reusable web components. I am not familiar with OpenUI5 so I would not be able to comment on this.